# how to do Server Side Rendering React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, serverside-javascript, server-side-rendering

I am working on a website which I want to render server-side. I am working on this but i am facing a lot many issues i even tried nextjs but with that I can't use react router. I tried other options also but every option gets stucked with some limitations after wasting hours on that. Any suggestions?

Comment: check this out boilerplate. It might help you. https:/github.com/Atyantik/react-pwa

Comment: Can't go with something having only 113 stars. Sorry

Comment: Aniruddh Agarwal now check stat. i hope after 800+ star you will approve it for your project.

Comment: Let it be some K first.

Comment: @Anirudhh repo has crossed 1K Star.

Comment: Good Bro @AjayPatel